# How to reference a strong named DLL without checking the specific version?

Tags: .net, dll, strongname

I have a C# project (MyProject.DLL) which references a third party component (ThirdParty.DLL) which has been "strong named".

I can't deploy an update to only ThirdParty.DLL because MyProject.DLL will only work with the version it was compiled with. I need to update both DLLs, even though one hasn't changed.

Can I reference a strong-named DLL and allow for updating them in the same way I can deploy updates to non-strong-named DLLs?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - Thanks for that. I've read that page several times but I can't see an answer to my question. Is what I want to do simply not possible?

Comment: Sorry, that link alone was a pretty poor comment. Yes, if `ThirdParty.dll` changed you can redirect (see `bindingRedirect`) and use another version (assuming that you do not re-deploy your manifest they have to ship that DLL with its own manifest, see _Redirecting assembly versions by using publisher policy_). If they changed the public key token then it's different. Short answer is "no, you can't" but there are some pretty dirty workarounds (easiest one I can think of is to handle `AssemblyResolve`).